# How to manipulate the view based on the itemsource count in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

if you are having any control example stacklayout or list,

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,15" x:Name="GoalsStack" BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Goaltemplateselector}" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FinalGoalList}">
</StackLayout>
```

Now you want to hide show this stacklayout based on the itemsource count without using any convertor.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code easily to perform any action using triggers

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,15" x:Name="GoalsStack" BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Goaltemplateselector}" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FinalGoalList}">
<StackLayout.Triggers>
<DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Path=FinalGoalList.Count}" Value="0">
<Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="20"/>
 </DataTrigger>
 </StackLayout.Triggers>
 </StackLayout>
```